# zsh function to create open new file in vim

Tags: zsh

I have the function below in my zsh config to edit a file in vim.

```
function note() {
  vim "~/.notes/$1.md";
}
```

So if I type 'note linux', it should either open `~/notes/linux.md` if it exists or create a new file.

However, with the above function, when I execute, Vim complains that linux.md is new directory? How do I force this name to be assumed as a filename, rather than a directory name?

Thanks

Comment: Does `~/.notes/` exist? Maybe add a `mkdir -p "~/.notes" to your function or .zshrc.

Comment: ~/.notes already exists so I wont need it in the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `~` doesn't seem to be expanded. Vim thinks you mean `./~/.notes/`, which is a new directory. Only quote the file name, not the directory like this:

```
function note() {
    vim ~/.notes/"$1.md"
}
```

or use `$HOME`:

```
function note() {
    vim "$HOME/.notes/$1.md"
}
```